How to ignore yml extension from prettier? .prettierignore doesn't work
I tried to create yml file to use github actions for flutter web deployment.
But I face error saying Invalid action input '...'.

Output terminal shows below error.
 ["INFO" - 오전 11:17:07] Extension Name: esbenp.prettier-vscode.
["INFO" - 오전 11:17:07] Extension Version: 10.4.0.
["INFO" - 오전 11:17:17] Formatting file:///Users/hayat/FlutterProjects/ProjectsFiles/injicare_event/.github/workflows/ci.yml
["INFO" - 오전 11:17:17] PrettierInstance:
{
  "modulePath": "/Users/hayat/node_modules/prettier/index.cjs",
  "importResolver": {},
  "callMethodResolvers": {},
  "currentCallMethodId": 2,
  "version": "3.1.1"
}
["INFO" - 오전 11:17:17] Using ignore file (if present) at /Users/hayat/FlutterProjects/ProjectsFiles/injicare_event/.prettierignore
["INFO" - 오전 11:17:17] File Info:
{
  "ignored": true,
  "inferredParser": null
}
["INFO" - 오전 11:17:17] File is ignored, skipping.
["INFO" - 오전 11:20:31] Formatting file:///Users/hayat/FlutterProjects/ProjectsFiles/injicare_event/.github/workflows/ci.yml
["INFO" - 오전 11:20:31] PrettierInstance:
{
  "modulePath": "/Users/hayat/node_modules/prettier/index.cjs",
  "importResolver": {},
  "callMethodResolvers": {},
  "currentCallMethodId": 5,
  "version": "3.1.1"
}
["INFO" - 오전 11:20:31] Using ignore file (if present) at /Users/hayat/FlutterProjects/ProjectsFiles/injicare_event/.prettierignore
["INFO" - 오전 11:20:31] File Info:
{
  "ignored": true,
  "inferredParser": null
}
["INFO" - 오전 11:20:31] File is ignored, skipping.


I guess this error comes from prettier.
Because I write as 'create-envfile' official document say exactly same.

So I add .prettierignore on my root path and write code to ignore yml file.
*.yml

But the result is same.
I also added below line to settings.json.
 "[yaml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },

But still prettier throws errors.
How to avoid this error?
